# mysql date & timestamp comparison help

Tags: mysql

hoping you guys can help - I have a timestamp column in my db table and i want to run a query to find any records from that table where the timestamp is the same as 7 days from now (ignoring the hours, minutes and seconds). So far I have this but I'm certain it's not what i should be doing:

```
WHERE `import_date` = 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 days)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE import_date = 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 days)'
```

should be

```
WHERE import_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)
```

`days` should be `day`

for timestamp same as 7 day before from now use

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`import_date`, "%Y-%m-%d") = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Thanks Salil, ah my mistake on the "day". I actually only want to look for an exact match with import_date and 7 days ago, which means I need to strip out the hours minutes and seconds of the timestamp and compare it with 7 days from the current date.